# How to solve problems with safari download files

Tags: finder, safari

I am on MacOS Mojave and I have not enough data, for now, to upgrade to Catalina. I am getting this extension(and shown still downloading) as shown below even though the download is finished. But the download is finished and it is shown so in the Safari web browser's downloads.

[image]

Also, some files are missing in the finder downloads folders but they are shown in the terminal when I list out the contents in the folder. How can I solve this before upgrading the MacOS?

Comment: Did you restart Safari/your Mac yet?

Comment: Actually I did restart earlier and it solved the problem. Then this was the second time this was happening.